# Artifacts after triangulation, while shading not affected

Tags: shaders

https://youtu.be/MzkKPdss7cw
Here's a video of the issue. As you can see, in Solid viewport mode everything works as expected. I'm using Fixed triangulation, which is what Blender seems to be doing by default. Shading is not affected whether triangulation is ON or OFF. As soon as I switch to Material Preview (or Render), my normal map becomes relevant and... Something breaks. You can see there's no custom split normals data. No double verts, only tris and quads. Does anyone have ideas what's going on? I need to triangulate before exporting, cause I use it in UE and triangulation method is different there. I can't bake normals AFTER triangulation either, cause I'm baking from Multires. Applying triangulation to multires'ed object messes it up.

Comment: Try the "Keep Normals" checkbox on the modifier.

Comment: I tried, forgot to mention, no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the answer is simply that this is an expected behavior. The normal map was baked for quads, not for  tris. Despite both triangulated and base mesh looking the same in Solid shading, normal data is not identical between them.

The question now is how useful is baking from multires then. I don't expect many people to use multires AFTER triangulation. Working on a triangulated topology is not easily readable. And, as I said, triangulating multiresed object messes it up. It would probably be good enough if I didn't use creases in the multires, but there seems to be no way of applying creases as deformation.